# clicking through all rows in a table from angular using selenium python web driver

Tags: python, html, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to iterate through a certain column of rows on a table/grid of an HTML page with I assume is a dynamic angular element.

I have tried to iterate through the rows by creating a list of common xpaths between each row. This only help me achieve 32 rows and not the full amount which is 332. I also tried waiting to see if the webpage would load and then have the full amount of web-elements. Then I tried to run a loop on searching for similar xpaths by scrolling down to the last element in the list. None of these ways helped me to iterate through the rows. Also I will not be able to share the website since the website is private.

#### python

```
webelement = []
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
ranSleep()
for webelement in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty"]'):
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

#### html for the rows

```
<a ng-model="row.entity.siteCode"
   ng-click="grid.appScope.openSite(row.entity)"
   style="cursor:pointer"
   class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-binding ng-scope ng-not-empty">
  Albuquerque&nbsp;
  <span title="Open defect(s) on site"
        ng-show="row.entity.openDeficiencies"
        style="background-color:yellow; color:#000;"
        class="ng-hide">
    &nbsp;!&nbsp;
  </span>
</a>
```

I expect to be able to click all the links in each row once this is solved

Here is the snippet of the html code

```html
<div id="table1" class="container-fluid">
    <div ui-i18n="en"
         class="grid advanceSearch ui-grid ng-isolate-scope grid1554731599680"
         id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions"
         ui-grid-expandable="" ui-grid-rowedit=""
         ui-grid-resize-columns="" ui-grid-selection=""
         ui-grid-edit="" ui-grid-move-columns="">
     <!-- TODO (c0bra): add "scoped" attr here, eventually? -->
     <style ui-grid-style="" class="ng-binding">
       .grid1554731599680 {
        /* Styles for the grid */
       }
```

[here is how the page looks with the table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDjIJ.png)

[image]

[Here is the rows that I want to click through all of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyL2x.png)

[image]

Comment: The AngularJS `ng-model` directive does not work with `<a>` anchor elements.

Comment: So how should I go about it? I'm pretty new with web-scraping

Answer (score 0):

You might still be able to increment through each link by appending to the class name, as they seem to be a little unique in nature and using the last number as a char from the alphabet. Perhaps something like below could work :) Expanding on the classname's last character, in-case there's an increase, should solve the problem of there being more than 26.

Steps taken: increment classnames >append successes to list >move to link within list >click link >List item

```
import string
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
successfulIncs = []

for char in alpha:
  className = 'ng-pristine.ng-scope.ui-grid-coluiGrid-000' + char
  try:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name(className)
        successfullIncs.append(className)

  except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Element not found")


### First move to our element
for line in successfulIncs:
  link = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located
  (By.CLASS_NAME, line))
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link).perform()

  #Click
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link).click(link).perform()
```

Comment: Program does work with that the cell sites eventually change with names is there another way

Comment: If you found all elements by class name "ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid ng-binding.ng-scope.ng-not-empty", what sort of output do you get? :)

Comment: I only get the first 32 links

Comment: Do you think there is something with tables in angular that I can use?

Comment: This is closed source so it's a little hard for me to tell, so i'll have to ask a few questions : ) For the 32 links that do appear, how many are you able to determine are still missing? Do the tables get populated when you navigate anywhere, up or down?

Comment: The remaining links that do not appear in the list is 313. About the table being populated when navigating up or down. I believe since the xpaths change accordingly when you scroll up or down, the xpaths are reused. So I believe they populate when you scroll up or down. Also when I try to capture all the site code links by class name only 32 of them are found.